# Two mutex condvar

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

If I have 2 mutexes locked, and I have a condvar for each one, is there an easy way to wait for *either* condvar to fire?  I want to leave holding both locks again, and with (at least) one of the condvars having been signaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redesign? Without knowing much about what you want to do: Try using one mutex and multiple condvars. If you want to wait for either condvar make a third condvar that is fired whenever the first one or second one is fired (or something like this).

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a test where I can't really get at one of the mutexes.  I guess I'll just keep mocking out more stuff until I'm down to one mutex.

Answer (score 1):

no easy way that i can see,  i would just create a third condvar and mutex, because you are really waiting for a different condition.

Answer (score 0):

No. You end up with a race condition. Imagine both signals are sent before `pthread_cond_wait` returns. One gets thrown away, and they're indistinguishable.

Another way to think, as Luke says, is that there are two different conditions happening. When you get the signal, you double-check the condition. If there are two conditions, there is clearly a race condition if the other condition may change while you are checking it.

The solution is to have two different threads. If those threads would need to be exclusive, use another lock to synchronize them.

Answer (score 0):

Just write synchronization functions that do exactly what you want. There's nothing built in that does this, but it's very straightforward to write.

One approach is to have a master wait table, protected by its own mutex. To wait, you allocate a new condition variable and new wait object. You fill in the wait object with what you're waiting for and your new condition variable. You acquire the master wait table mutex, add your object to the master wait table, and block on your own condition variable. To signal, you change whatever the predicates are, acquire the mutex on the master wait table, see which threads have their conditions met, and signal each of their dedicated condition variables.

On wakeup, you'll have to acquire individual mutexes and re-check individual predicates. It won't be done automatically.

But most likely, the right solution is to redesign. The most logical redesign -- **Why is one thread waiting for two different conditions?** If there two things that might happen and two different things that need to be done when they happen, why is one thread doing both things?

Usually, the best design change is to not have threads wait for these kinds of things. Instead, when work needs to be done, have the thread that discovered the condition that means work needs to be done add a work item to a queue. Then worker threads can wait for jobs to be placed on that queue. If there are two different conditions that need to be handled, there are two jobs that can be done by any thread.